# Installing Android OS into Windows

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, android

Is it possible to install **android** operating system into a 32-bit **windows 7** system via **virtual box**? If yes please help me do that.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/  First google result for 'android virtualbox' :)

Comment: Thanks. I have started downloading the android iso file. But it seems a zip file is downloading. Will the iso file be inside the archive? @shub

Comment: Did you go [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list)? It's an iso download. Top link

Comment: Yes, I was going exactly there. @shub

Comment: I have found why my iso was downloading as a zip file. Look through this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/207105/windows-vista-shows-iso-file-as-zip) for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

**Yes** it is possible.

Why?

Because [Android is based on the Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) (on a very low scale), and so you can run Android as a VM just like any Linux distribution.

How:

Instructions via [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/):

1. Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).
2. Download the [Android x86 ISO](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list)
3. Open VirtualBox. Click New:

   - Name: Anything
   - Type: Linux
   - Version: Linux 2.6
4. Start the VM. Select the iso you downloaded
5. Select 'Installation' via keyboard
6. Create/Modify Partitions
7. New > Enter > Primary > Enter > Enter
8. Bootable > Enter > Write > Enter > 'yes' > Enter
9. Quit
10. Select new partition > Enter
11. ext3 file system > Yes > Yes > Yes
12. Remove iso from VM, reboot.

That's it.

P.S. *Please* [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=android%20virtualbox&oq=and&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j69i60j69i61l2j69i59j69i65.1992j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) first, next time :)

Comment: What does P.S. mean? @shub

Comment: @Ramvignesh http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postscript

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to install android operating system into a 32-bit windows 7 system via virtual box?

Yes, as Android is based on a Linux kernel at the lowest levels, you would follow similar instructions for setting up a Linux VM on VirtualBox or whichever virtualization software you use.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial [at HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/) (thanks [@shub](https://superuser.com/users/316136/shub)) shows how to install Android in VirtualBox.
I'll try to paraphrase the article.

You need to firstly install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), and then get the [Android x86 ISO image](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list). Create a VM, configured as Linux 2.6, with at least 512 MB of RAM, and 3 GB or more of disk space. You can then power on, and then follow the on-screen instructions to get started. Remember to create a partition, and make it bootable.